# Check that a stubbed method is called three times

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

How do I check that a stubbed method has been called three times during another method call in rspec?

I have a method `parse_list`, which calls another method `parse_item`:

```
def parse_list(html)
  ...
end

def parse_item(html)
  ...
end
```

How can I test that the latter is called three times from the former?

Comment: https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/v/2-13/docs/message-expectations/receive-counts

Answer (score 3):

It depends on which object you are calling `parse_list` method. You simply need to `expect(object).to receive(:parse_item).with(arguments).exactly(n).times`
For more details [click](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/v/2-13/docs/message-expectations/receive-counts#expect-a-message-at-least-(n)-times)